Grizzly output buffer is null; can't write
My Jakarta EE application sometimes starts with error about Grizzly but some not. Websocket part in the application is in Application Scope, run on Payara 6.2024.10, full-profile, and JDK17. The error is not often shown. When had error, the messages were generated every seconds.
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.canWrite()" because "this.grizzlyOutputBuffer" is null

I appreciate any help.
